# Google Analytics Performance

Tags: google-analytics, link-prefetching, cors

We are using Google Analytics on our website. The last two resources loaded are from googletagmanager.com and google-analytics.com.  The download time for these two resources is a total of 370ms for users distant from our web server (San Jose, CA to Sydney, Australia).  This is a great deal of time compared to our On Load time of 1.1 seconds.

Our first attempt to increase the performance of this website was to add the following code:

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.googletagmanager.com/" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://www.googletagmanager.com/" />
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://www.google-analytics.com/" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://www.google-analytics.com/" />
```

This eliminated the dns query times.  This change is included in the performance timings stated above.

We are trying to:

```
<link rel="preload" as="script" href="https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js" type="script" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

This is causing a CORS error, "Ensure CORS response header values are valid".  How should I correct this error?  Is it a good idea to prefect this script?

Comment: Google analytics should be loading asynchronously and it doesn't need to load before your site starts functioning.  Is there a reason that you need to improve its load time?  Users shouldn't notice the delay.

Comment: We have "<script async src="/sites/default/files/google_analytics/gtag.js?r4dzme"></script>" at the very top of <head> -- thus async is in place.  As I mentioned above, about 1/3 of our webpage OnLoad time is google analytics.  Should I not be concerned about this?